# Is there any limit (how many) of collections per database, per account or per subscription for Cosmos Db?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to know max number of collection which can be add in cosmos Database.

Comment: This is really a service / subscription question, and not a programming question (therefore off-topic here). You can open a billing support ticket (which is free to do), to check your subscription's limit, but there's really not a specific limit (collections are billable containers, so as long as you can pay for them...).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there are no limits in number of collections that can be added to a cosmos DB.

But be aware: Each collection is purchased! 5 collections are costs 5 times more than one collection. (if they all have the same RU/s).

A good pattern is to put all data into one single collection and add a `.type` property for each document. With that `.type` your query the data you want to get.

`SELECT * FROM c 
 WHERE c.type = <myDataType>`